# Autocapitalization of words does not work in UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got a `UITextView` that needs to autocapitalize words. However, when I call any of these methods, the view does not respond.

```
[self.fullNameTextView setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
self.fullNameTextView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Is this a bug in iOS 8.1?

Comment: Have you verified that `self.fullNameTextView` isn't `nil` when trying to set the autocapitalization type?

Comment: Just to verify, you're trying to capitalize user-entered text, not text you are setting programatically, correct? It will only capitalize text that the user types.

Comment: Yes, I want to auto capitalize the words the user types.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by settings my Keyboard type back to DEFAULT:

[image]

Comment: This is kind of stupid, but thank you for letting me know. I was already a bit suspicious before, but for some reason hadn't tested it out this way.

Answer (score 8):

Please check your device Settings → General → Keyboard → Auto-Capitalization is turned on.

[image: Keyboards Settings]

Comment: Wow, this would never cross my mind, and in my case this was the stupid issue.. thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are valid of setting the property are valid. Are you testing using the simulator?

I found that autocapitalisation works only if you disable the hardware keyboard in `Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard` (Uncheck) and use the onscreen software keyboard. I tested this with iOS 8.1 with both UITextField and UITextView.

**Edit**

These properties determine the behaviour during manual input only. If you require the capitalisation of text that you are setting programmatically into the text view, use the following method:

```
NSString *myString = @"this is my uncapitalised string";
self.fullNameTextView.text = [myString capitalizedString]
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your textview? What do you mean exactly when you say the view does not respond? Can you not edit the text view at all? I mocked up a simple test view controller with both a UITextView and UITextField and it is working as expected.

Comment: Via storyboards and added a subclass that creates a dotted line placeholder. Didn't do anything with capitalization type

Comment: Ok, I think I get you. I will update the answer to what I think your problem is.

Comment: Thanks applejack, however i need this to work with manual input.. Is there anything that could disturb the behaviour of setting the capitalisation?

Comment: In what method are you calling self.fullNameTextView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;?

Comment: Calling in Viewdidload.

Comment: Ok that sound fine. So what you are saying is, the app runs but when you type in manual input with the software keyboard there is not auto capitalisation? Have you tried remove all other custom code? Have you also tried deleting are readding your UITextView from you storyboard to ensure that have not changed anything from the defaults accidentally?

Comment: jup, found a more specific bug now: I'm indenting the textview with spaces, because there's a label on the same line. Those spaces cannot and should not be edited. However, when I remove the line     self.fullNameTextView.text = [self.fullNameTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) withString:@"     "]; the capitalisation works..

Comment: Ok, so we have established that it is not a bug. It is probably where you are making the above call. Could you possibly hide your place holder when there is at least one character of text in your textview? Your NSMakeRange is also suspect as you are make a range from index 0 with a length of zero.

Comment: Figured it out. Weirdest thing ever. Calling     `[self.fullNameTextView setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];`
 before     `self.fullNameTextView.text = [self.fullNameTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) withString:@"     "];` seemed to do the job.. reversed it didn't.. Would you know why?

Comment: I assume you are doing this in viewDidLoad. It looks like once the text is set it is ignoring any future changes to the autocapitalizationType.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.fullNameTextView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

**Note:** It will not work if its simulator or Auto-Capitalisation is turned off from Settings>General>Keyboard>Auto-Capitalisation on iOS/iDevice. this solution doesn't work if auto correction is disabled for text view.

Comment: How is the code any different than what the poster has?